# Resize or turn off encrypted swap

Tags: encryption, swap

I installed ubuntu 14.04.1 on a 60 GB ssd with full encryption. My PC has 16 GB of RAM.

This has resulted in a swap size approaching 16 GB. Can I subsequently change this to 2 GB or completely turn swap off. I need more space for programs and files instead of swap.

I never use hibernation mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn off swap with command

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

After that you can resize or delete existing or do something ...
If you only resize swap probably you do not have to made some change in `/etc/fstab/`

Swap can be added like swap file.
Try with this command to add swap of 2 GB

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1k count=2048k
mkswap /swapfile
swapon /swapfile
/swapfile none swap sw 0 0
```

Edit 1

On the following [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ResizeEncryptedPartitions) you have manual to re-size encrypted partitions, also [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=726724)

Comment: The system is full encrypted, how do I re-size the swap I can't see it in gparted...?

Comment: you have my edit 1 in answer